# Resolve Gradle Dependency into local JAR in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, jar, dependency-management

Currently, my Android app project compiles against a local library project like so:

```
// build.gradle

dependencies {
    compile project(':Library-Project')
    compile files('libs/library.jar') // Resolve into this if Library-Project is not available
}
```

The local library project builds into `library.jar` and is placed in the `libs` folder.

Is there a way to fallback on the `library.jar` artifact if the local project is not present *without* commenting `compile project(':Library-Project')` in lieu of compiling against the jar?

Answer (score 0):

Used a more dynamic approach for which dependency should actually get compiled.

```
dependencies {
    // Check if the local project exists, and compile against that if it does
    if ( new File("/Library-Project").exists() )
    {
        compile project(':Library-Project')
    }
    // Local project DNE, compile against JAR file
    else
    {
        compile files('libs/library.jar')
    }
}
```

Another way to automatically compile all JAR files in the `/libs` folder is by adding the following line within your `dependencies` block:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```